# PHP HTML JQUERY Submit button class change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this little form , that works as a filter. All I want is to send values to URL and regarding of value show active button.
Form is working

```
<form id="filter" method="get" action="">
<label>View:
<input type="submit" id="men" class="active" name="men" value="men" />
<input type="submit" id="women" class="normal" name="women" value="women" />
</label>
</Form>
```

But when it comes to changing classes, it does not work
There are 2 classes (normal=normal, active=highlighted)

```
$('#men').click(function() {
       $('#women').removeClass('active');
       $('#women').addClass('normal');
       $(this).removeClass('normal');
       $(this).addClass('active'); 
return false;
});

$('#women').click(function() {
       $('#men').removeClass('active');
       $('#men').addClass('normal');
       $(this).removeClass('normal');
       $(this).addClass('active');  
 return false;
});
```

Without Jquery , button click changes the URL

With JQUERY - The toogle works, but it does not changes URL
How this could be solved? 
Thank You!

Comment: Can you post JSFiddle for this? With CSS too

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/acT9G/

Comment: Can you verify that the event listeners are actually being called, by putting an alert('click') or console.log('click') inside of them? Is it possible that you have other objects on the page with the id "men" or "women"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about what you try to achieve, but this work:

```
$('#men').click(function(evt) {
   evt.preventDefault();
   if($(this).hasClass('normal')){
       $(this).toggleClass('normal active');
       $('#women').toggleClass('normal active');
    }
});

$('#women').click(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault(); // this will prevent submitting your form
    if($(this).hasClass('normal')){
        $('#men').toggleClass('normal active');
        $(this).toggleClass('normal active');  
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/acT9G/2/)

---

EDIT: maybe i'm wrong but based on your comment you seems to need to reload the page to get the result of the form submit. So why not doing your `class` switch in PHP?

```
<?php
    $menBtnClass = 'normal';
    $womenBtnClass = 'normal';

    if(isset($_GET['men']) && $_GET['men'] === 'men') $menBtnClass = 'active';
    if(isset($_GET['women']) && $_GET['women'] === 'women') $womenBtnClass = 'active';
?>
<form id="filter" method="get" action="">
    <label>View:
    <input type="submit" id="men" class="<?php echo $menBtnClass; ?>" name="men" value="men" />
    <input type="submit" id="women" class="<?php echo $womenBtnClass; ?>" name="women" value="women" />
    </label>
</form>
```

Comment: The toogle works, it changes classes. But it does not changes $GET value anymore

Comment: ok you should edit your question and add your PHP code. I think you dont need javascript for what your try to achieve. Just check your `$_GET` value and add `class` in PHP.

Comment: I done  it. With PHP. Correct, there is no need for javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$('#men').click(function() {
       $(this).toggleClass('normal active');
       $('#women').toggleClass('normal active');

return false;
});

$('#women').click(function() {
       $('#men').toggleClass('normal active');
       $(this).toggleClass('normal active');
 return false;
});
```

toggleClass is most effective https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Answer (score 0):

What is not working?

Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/X8EqK/

Seems to work for me

```
$('#men').click(function() {
       $('#women').removeClass('active');
       $('#women').addClass('normal');
       $(this).removeClass('normal');
       $(this).addClass('active'); 
       return false;
});

$('#women').click(function() {
       $('#men').removeClass('active');
       $('#men').addClass('normal');
       $(this).removeClass('normal');
       $(this).addClass('active');  
       return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong? It's working in my test: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nybryx/Ewy9a/)

```
$('#men').click(function() {
   $('#women').removeClass('active').addClass('normal');
   $(this).removeClass('normal').addClass('active'); 
   return false;
});

$('#women').click(function() {
   $('#men').removeClass('active').addClass('normal');
   $(this).removeClass('normal').addClass('active');  
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V4XrH/1/) Works well here as well. I have only nudged the code a bit.

```
$(function() {

    $('#men').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $('#women').removeClass('active').addClass('normal');
       $(this).removeClass('normal').addClass('active'); 
    });

    $('#women').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $('#men').removeClass('active').addClass('normal');
       $(this).removeClass('normal').addClass('active');
    }); 

});
```